# What is wrong with my class and extends code?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

```
class shape;
  protected integer width, height;
  
  function void set_width(integer w);
     width = w;
  endfunction
  
  function void set_height(integer h);
     height = h;
  endfunction
  
endclass


class rectangle extends shape;
  
  function integer area();
    return(width * height);
  endfunction
  
endclass


module test;
  rectangle rect;
  
  initial begin
    rect.set_height(3);
    rect.set_width(5);
    $display("%d", rect.area);
  end
    
endmodule
```

I use system verilog to code. Why this code is not giving output?
What does this error mean?

> xmsim: *E,TRNULLID: NULL pointer dereference.

what I want is check and test my class and extends.

Answer (score 1):

You have taken handle `rect` of class `rectangle` but haven't assigned it memory. To allocate a `rectangle` object, you need to use `new()`. `rect` is a rectangle handle, call `new` function to construct the rectangle object.

```
rectangle rect;
rect = new();
```